# Create and Update as one action in CRUD

Tags: php, design-patterns, crud, database-abstraction

Is there a reason why Create and Update are distinct when making MVC application in PHP?

I see why they are distinct in theoretical explanations, but is it worth keeping separate actions and views for create and update in CRUD controller? If I only need to change the title of save button it seems logical to have one action for both create and update operations. which will save object as new DB row or update existing depending on the id it has (or hasn't).

PS. I've always merged them into one action and recently when started searching for information about Zend Framework I've found that every tutorial with some CRUD functionality has distinct create and update actions and views that have almost the same code. It seems strange why authors copy-paste 90% of the code from one method to another.

Answer (score 2):

I think you're asking more of a style question than a purely functional one. For me it's separation of concerns - there is no guarantee that create and update will truly overlap, and there may well be functional differences, so it's a potential landmine in the future to lump them together.